# conditional statement for contact form not working

Tags: javascript, if-statement, conditional-statements

Im trying to first, check if both fields are not empty. if empty, alert user its empty. Then check if both user and password math and if they do match, then alert('welcome'). but if I type anything in the boxes, it passes and says welcome? Help!

```
const container = document.querySelector('.container');
const userInput = document.querySelector('#username');
const passInput = document.querySelector('#password');
const button = document.querySelector('button');

button.addEventListener('click', () => {
    if (!userInput.value || !passInput.value) {
        alert('One or more fields are empty. Please enter password and username');
    }
    if (!userInput.value == 'user21' || !passInput.value == 'user21') {
        alert('password or username inavlid')
    } else if (userInput.value == 'user21' && passInput.value == 'user21') {
        alert(`Welcome ${userInput.value}`);
    }
})*
```

Comment: In general, you should write `x != y` rather than `!x == y`

Answer (score 1):

Remove * at the end of your code and put ;

Answer (score 0):

This:

```
if (!userInput.value == 'user21' || !passInput.value == 'user21') {
```

evaluates the `!` first. It's like:

```
if ((!userInput.value) == 'user21' || (!passInput.value) == 'user21') {
```

which of course won't result in the comparison you want.

Check if the username and password match, and if they don't, just have a plain `else`, without an `else if` there.

```
button.addEventListener('click', () => {
    if (!userInput.value || !passInput.value) {
        alert('One or more fields are empty. Please enter password and username');
    } else if (userInput.value == 'user21' && passInput.value == 'user21') {
        alert(`Welcome ${userInput.value}`);
    } else {
        alert('password or username inavlid')
    }
})
```

Also consider

- using a [proper modal instead of `alert`](https://softwareengineering.stackexchange.com/questions/106031/javascripts-prompt-confirm-and-alert-considered-old-fashioned)
- if this is something you want any sort of reasonable security for, validate the logins using a backend database instead of hard-coding it on the front-end (which is trivially bypassable)

Comment: Oh wow! I over complicated this. Thank you so much!